# Optimizing integral functionals using Matlab

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-optimization

I am looking for some bibliography regarding solving integral optimization problems numerically (preferably using Matlab).

> I want to solve problems of the type
>   $$ \min_{r \in A} \int_a^b (f(x,r(x),r'(x))dx  $$
>   where $A$ is a class of admissibility for $r$, where some constraints may appear.

I am not looking for a general method to solve all these problems. In my case $f$ is usually a very simple function. I just want to see some examples solved in detail, so that I could try and adapt the methods to my case.

I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it appears I misread the question. I can't say that I have seen a matlab solution for the problem that you are posting here.

Answer (score 1):

The general problem you stated belongs to [the Calculus of variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations).
To give you a general idea of how to solve this let me adapt your notation.

We want to minimize
\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x,y(x),y'(x) \,dx \text{ for } y\in A
\end{align}
Where $A$ is a class of function.
To minimize the above integral we need to solve the [Euler Lagrange Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}f_{y'} -f_y&=0
\\ \Leftrightarrow f_{y'x}+f_{y'y}y'+f_{y'y'}y''&=f_y
\end{align}
Which is a 2nd order differential equation for y, as f is known. This method is called indirect method.

To give you an concrete example, I think you could read [this](http://www.math.nps.navy.mil/~bneta/4311.pdf) .pdf starting at chapter 7.1.1 It starts with the general theory and gives you the matlab code for an explicit example.